# What tools similar to Tag&Rename exist?

Tags: mp3, tags, flac, aac

I've got a media library consisting of a set of roughly 8000 MP3 (purchased from Amazon MP3), AAC (purchased from the iTunes Music Store - Unencrypted), and FLAC (ripped from my own physical disks) files. Tags are broken on a large number of these; particularly where album art is concerned. My previous standby for dealing with such matters, [Tag&Rename](https://superuser.com/questions/153894/music-tagging-software-more-consistent-than-tagrename), seems to have been abandoned by it's developer, Softpointer. Moreover, it has some pretty serious bugs that have destroyed tags on these files on multiple occasions in certain circumstances.

I'm looking for a tool that can do something similar. Most of the "Built-In-Media-Player-Tagger" tools don't know how to deal with album art correctly (e.g. both Winamp and iTunes don't update album art in the media files; they merely place the album art in their own databases), or (sadly) cannot deal with FLAC files.

Answer (score 3):

[MP3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) is what I use. It embeds album art and handles nearly every file type I routinely use, including FLAC.

Comment: +1. MP3Tag is one of the best metadata editing software I have found on Windows. It also has decent support for MusicBrainz so it can help you fix the broken tags on all of your songs in one go.

Comment: I'd never used this until today, but it seems solid but unclutered. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have been [using MP3Nity](http://www.littlelan.com/mp3nity/) for many years in Windows, It does about everything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[TagScanner 5.1](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/). Cant beat the ease of use. Stable and fast. Locks in album art, lyrics, tag info and has a easy rename platform.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the product, perhaps a screenshot, and some more info about how it works/what it does? Also, if you are affiliated with the product, please make sure to check our [FAQ#promotion] for info about self-promotion policies. Cheers!